# Absolute solution for building opencv with Visual Studio 2012 on 64-bit Windows 8 Machine

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012, windows-8

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 8 64-bit machine and try to use opencv and VS2012 together. Even the solution on opencv website doesn't work well and causes library linking errors. So is there anyone who found a strict solution about using 3 of them (VS2012, Win8, opencv) together? Opencv version doesn't matter. Any help appriciated.

Comment: Try to read this [How to build applications with OpenCV inside the Microsoft Visual Studio](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html#windows-visual-studio-how-to). It works for me (vs 2012, win8 64bits). Also make sure that your project configured to the right platform (32bit/64bit).

Comment: @Edgar which opencv version do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution on this video tutorial:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cgo0UitHfp8

I have installed VS2012 before and I installed VS2010. They work fine together. Then I followed the steps on tutorial and it works fine now.

Note: I installed opencv version 2.4.3.